# Temporarily suppressing standard-output

Tags: print

Suppose I have a function that is 'noisy' and prints to standard output rudely.

```
(defun not-my-noisy-function ()
  "A function outside my control"
  (do-something-useful)
  (print "Haha! Butts!"))
```

I would like to be able to make calls to that function without corresponding messages in stdout.  I was hoping that there was an elisp construct which would evaluate the form discarding standard-output from its body.  A little bit like `ignore-errors`, but applicable to an output stream instead of thrown exceptions.  I haven't been about to find anything in the vein of "suppress"/"silent"/"discard"/"redirect" for output streams.

```
(evaluate-silently ;; macro I wish existed
  (not-my-noisy-function))
```

My first thought of setting `standard-output` to nil doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
(let ((standard-output nil))
  (print "Nope; doesn't work.  You can still hear me."))
```

Interestingly the elisp manual says it must *not* be nil and doesn't say anything about values other than `t`, a buffer, or a marker.  I can't seem to find documentation about an "real" streams in the elisp manual; only optional parameters to output functions which only seem to duplicate captured standard output rather redirecting it.  `with-output-to-string` and `with-output-to-temp-buffer` also only seem to duplicate output to a buffer.

As a last recourse I could manually examine problematic functions and use `cl-flet` (to override `print`,`message`, etc), but I would rather not take that approach.  Unfortunately this is the only technique that I've identified to accomplish this.

```
(cl-flet ((print (&rest body) nil))
  (not-my-noisy-function)
  (print "I am being ignored!?!!"))
```

Is there a better way?  I hope I just haven't divined the correct `apropos` incantation.

Answer (score 3):

You were following a good line of enquiry regarding `standard-output`, but just didn't manage to find the right information.

The value of `standard-output` has to be a valid value for the `PRINTCHARFUN` argument, which <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `print` describes nicely:

```
Optional argument PRINTCHARFUN is the output stream, which can be one
of these:

   - a buffer, in which case output is inserted into that buffer at point;
   - a marker, in which case output is inserted at marker's position;
   - a function, in which case that function is called once for each
     character of OBJECT's printed representation;
   - a symbol, in which case that symbol's function definition is called; or
   - t, in which case the output is displayed in the echo area.

If PRINTCHARFUN is omitted, the value of `standard-output' (which see)
is used instead.
```

Hence you can simply bind `standard-output` to the canonical function for doing nothing:

```el
(let ((standard-output 'ignore))
  (print "hello"))
```